# How to get output that shows which Computer is enabled/disabled

Tags: powershell, active-directory

What should I add to the following command to get the values for enabled or disabled computer?

Thanks in advance!

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name, CanonicalName,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,ipv4Address | Export-CSV c:\ADcomputerslist.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADComputer` Cmdlet [returns one or more instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=windowsserver2022-ps) of [`ADComputer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adcomputer?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) class. It has a `Enabled` property which you can use along with `-Filter` to filter out all `enabled/disabled` computers.

```
$enabledComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Enabled -eq $true" -Property * 
$disabledComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Enabled -eq $false" -Property *
```